# How to avoid rerendering all child components which are created by v-for directive

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component, vuex, v-for

There is a  list of child component

```
 <question-list-item
        v-for="(item, index) in questionListParsed"
        :key="item.id"
        :both-question="item"
        :class-id="classId"
        :subject-id="subjectId"
        :index="index+1"
      />
```

and the **questionListParsed** is a getter in vuex.

```
  /**************************************************************************
   * getters
   **************************************************************************/
  get questionListParsed(): QuestionListItemRes[] {
    const { questionList, showingOriginalQuestion } = this
    const questionListParsed = questionList.map((e) => {
      const recommendQuestion = e.recommendedQuestions[0]
      const recommendQuestionIds = showingOriginalQuestion[e.questionNumber]
      let arr = []
      if (recommendQuestionIds) {
        arr = recommendQuestionIds.filter((item) => {
          return !this.removedRecommendQuestionIds.includes(item)
        })
      }
      return {
        recommendQuestion: {
          ...recommendQuestion,
          stem: recommendQuestion.question,
          knowledges: splitMultiKnowledge(recommendQuestion.knowledge),
          questionSourceList: recommendQuestion.sources,
          categoryId: recommendQuestion.categoryId,
        },
        originalQuestion: {
          ...e,
          id: e.questionNumber,
          stem: e.question,
          difficulty: e.complexity,
          knowledges: splitMultiKnowledge(e.knowledge),
        },
        id: recommendQuestion.id, 
        questionSimilarId: e.questionNumber, 
        mistakeAnswerId: e.id,
        targetExerciseId: e.targetExerciseId,
        status: recommendQuestion.status,
      }
    })

    return questionListParsed
  }
```

and the **questionListParsed** is mainly depends on the state **questionList** whitch is the originnal data from server side. Now i change **questionList** by the following way

```
  @Mutation
  updateQuestionListByIndex(data: UpdateParams): void {
    if (data.value) {
      const temp = [...this.questionList]
      temp[data.index] = data.value
      this.questionList = temp
    }
  }
```

and commit the mutation inside an Action like these

```
        this.context.commit('updateQuestionListByIndex', {
          index: targetIndex,
          value: originQuestion[0],
        })
```

I just want to change one item in the array **questionList**  and then **questionListParsed** changed.
The expectation is that **only one component updated** but all of the child component updated(use console.log('updated') in its **updated hocks**).

**How to do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why all components are updated is because you use computed property (Vuex getters are Vue computed properties).

Whenever anything in `questionList` is changed, `questionListParsed` is recomputed and because you are using `map` and generating new objects, the result is a new array with  completely new objects --> every child in list is updated

I would not consider it a problem because in reality only the DOM elements of the changed item are updated (that is the beauty of virtual DOM). If you do see some performance problem, the way around it is to stop using `computed`/getters and instead do the transformation only once when data is loaded and continue to work only with `questionListParsed`

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you about virtual DOM. But I have a need to click a button to recall the server`s api to update questionList. So I originally planned to use a getter. What should i do if i only use questionListParsed

Comment: Do you actually see any performance problem in your app ? Some operation are slow or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prevent the child components from rerendering, Vue does that for you. By providing a unique key to each list element `:key="item.id"` you give Vue a hint about the item, so Vue can identify and reuse the already rendered parts.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key for more information.